# isset($_FILES returning FALSE

Tags: php, isset

've got this bit of code which works on one part of my website but not on another;

Working part - this returns true;

```
 echo '<td><input type="file" name="fileUpload"></td>';
       if(isset($_FILES["fileUpload"]["name"]))
```

Broken part = this returns false;

```
 if(isset($productimageURL)){
    echo '<td><img src="'.$productimageURL.'" style="max-height: 100px; max-width: 100px;"/>
   `<br><input type="file" name="fileUpload" /></td>';
    }
    if(isset($_FILES["fileUpload"]["name"])){
```

I have both forms containing the necessary `enctype="multipart/forms-data"` and I've succesfully managed to upload files with one part of my website but I can't get the 2nd part  to pick up the file.

Comment: Not sure if it will make a difference but try `enctype="multipart/form-data"` (You had an 's' after `/form`)

Comment: @MarioSegura oh dear, that's where it is! Thanks